# Export UserControl to other project

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

(In VS 2008) I made a usercontrol which created 3 files (.vb, .resx, .Designer.vb).

How do I export this to another project. Btw, I want to **edit/change the usercontrol in that new project**.

Can I just copy those 3 files to the new project folder and include them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, right click on the new project, Add > Existing Item... , then select the files to add.

Or, if it happens to be a new project within the same solution, you should just be able to copy&paste/drag between the projects.

Comment: This will change the existing files when he starts modifying the control.  This might not be intended.

Comment: Thanks!  Add>Existing Item seems to work and makes new files, not referencing the old. Drag/drop idk, didn't try.